# Mockito argument validation - invalid use of argument matchers

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

This question has been asked many times and I have checked the answers and they dont answer my qestion.
Here is my code:

```
when(birtReportRendererService.generateReport(isA(ReportConfig.class), isA(ReportOutputTypeEnum.class), isA(Map.class)))
                .thenReturn(new ByteArrayOutputStream())
```

and this is the error I am getting:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException: 
Invalid use of argument matchers!
0 matchers expected, 3 recorded:
```

It is pretty explanatory ( I dont have to mix matchers with literal values).
But I am not doing this on my code.

Update

---

This is the method I am testing:

```
java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream generateReport(ReportConfig reportConfig, ReportOutputTypeEnum reportType, Map<String, String> reportParams) {
    // code
}
```

Comment: Can you share a [minimal test case](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reproduces this problem?

Comment: argument matching is causing the problem, dont you think providing the argument types is enough?

Comment: Without context, the code you posted above looks fine.  So something else must be going on...

Comment: paste more of the test method to see how you create the mock, and paste more of the birtReportRendererService class to see if it cannot be mocked by mockito.